# Failed to coerce slice entry of type TensorVariable to integer

Tags: python, theano

I was following the code on one of the books about deep learning, where the author uses theano as a library for this kind of networks. When I try to run the code:

```
i = T.lscalar() # mini-batch index
    train_mb = theano.function(
        [i], cost, updates=updates,
        givens={
            self.x:
            training_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            training_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })
```

I get the following error: "IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type TensorVariable to integer".
The call of that theano function looks like this:

```
cost_ij = train_mb(minibatch_index)
```

So, basically, looks like the `i` is not evaluated and python tries to use TensorVariable instead of normal integer, though I pass a normal integer as function parameter. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: it's strange, but it turns out that I had my data in a slightly wrong shape.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the same problem as I did,
please visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/39064543/6740140
Hope it can help you.